# How can I set the value of a protected var in a mock test (CakePHP)

Tags: cakephp, mocking, phpunit, cakephp-2.6

I want to test a Shell that calls an API. The Shell has a function that sets the value for a protected var `protected $_credential = [];`

```
class ImportShell extends AppShell
{
    protected $_credential = [];

    public function sales() {
        $credential = $this->Credential->find('first', [
            'conditions' => [
                'Credential.id' => $this->args[0]
            ]
        ]);
        $this->_credential = $credential;
    }
}
```

It uses the values in `$this->args` to find a Table entry and write that result into `$_credential`

**How can I access/change `$_credential` in my test when I use it like this?**

```
$ImportShell = $this->getMockBuilder('ImportShell')
    ->setMethods(array('find'))
    ->getMock();

$ImportShell->sales();
```

**Also how can I access/change `$this->args`?**

Answer (score 1):

### Use reflections

[Reflections](http://php.net/manual/en/intro.reflection.php) provide a mechanism to modify and interrogate code, and has a specific function to [set a property value](http://php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.setvalue.php). The syntax is a little unwheildy but this allows you to modify the accessibility and value of class properties (and functions). Something like this would do what you want:

```
$class = new ReflectionClass("ImportShell");
$property = $class->getProperty("_credential");
$property->setAccessible(true);

$ImportShell = $this->getMockBuilder('ImportShell')
    ->setMethods(array('find'))
    ->getMock();
$ImportShell->_credential = ['stuff'];
```

### There's a plugin for that

The [Friends Of Cake Test Utilities plugin](https://github.com/FriendsOfCake/cakephp-test-utilities) simplifies the syntax to achieve the same thing. The syntax using this plugin would be:

```
$this->setProtectedProperty('_credential', ['stuff'], $ImportShell);
```

### Is it really necessary though?

[args is a public property](https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/blob/2.x/lib/Cake/Console/Shell.php#L94). Instead of manipulating a protected property, it is possible to simply set the public property that is used to populate it before calling the test function.

```
$ImportShell = $this->getMockBuilder('ImportShell')
    ->setMethods(array('find'))
    ->getMock();

$ImportShell->args = ['stuff'];
$ImportShell->sales();
```

Though given the way the question is phrased, it'd probably make more sense to mock the Credential model and add an expectation that it'll be called, and return what you want it to.

Comment: Thanks.
Though the first bit does not work.
The FoC plugin is for cake 3 (I work with cakePhp 2.6).
But I am calling a public function now and pass the args in the test as you described

Comment: The first code block is off the cuff code (so it may contain an error though in principle it should be correct) - "does not work" is not helpful/clear, but check/compare to the php docs if there's an error. You're right, sorry it is a 3.x plugin - but it's just a trait with no dependencies, if you choose to you can use it just like any other php vendor code.